# Ordnance Survey API - a couple of questions

Tags: api, ordnance-survey

Regarding OS maps API - is there a way to crop the map to show just the area I am studying?

OS Download API - I have generated the API and added it into QGIS, and I am following the directions from here - https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/downloads/gettingStarted
When i try to connect, i get the error 'error occurred while parsing element'

(I am dyspraxic and dyslexic, so i struggle to understand things sometimes)

Comment: I would use OS Hub directly with QGIS [wfs/wms] here is a guide https://osdatahub.os.uk/docs/wfs/gettingStarted (QGIS)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

The OS Downloads API provides an automated way to download/manage the OS datasets in their native/raw formats. It is what is used behind the scenes in the Downloads section of the Data Hub (https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open). The downloadable data will either cover the entirety of GB; or you may have the option to download the information in 100km areas. Once you have physically downloaded any of the datasets - you can load/display them in a GIS application of your choosing (e.g. QGIS).

If your requirement is more to make arbitrary requests for data - then you can use the OS Maps API or OS Vector Tile API for base maps; and the OS Features API to access/overlay vector geometries with their associated attribution.